# Why are many small square divs rendered differently?

Tags: css

Why are many small square divs rendered differently? There are rectangle blocks where it seems like there's no margin but wider borders instead.

[image: block with tiny divs]

They are perfect squares 5.7px*5.7px. When zooming this effect disappers as seen on the attached screenshot.
[image: zoomed small divs]

Maybe this behavior is due to the sceen resolution, if this is the case how is this can be escaped then?
Haven't found any similar questions, maybe because this is not the common case as canvas is supposed to be used for rendering such objects, but I have to use divs as I have never used canvas yet and haven't much time to dive in it before deadline.
 Thanks!

Comment: are you on 100% Zoom?
If not, make sure you use Pixel (px) coordinates and not relative coordinates

Comment: @Raildex, yes, it is 100 and I'm using Pixels: `.Pixel {
  display: block;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  width: 5.7px;
  height: 5.7px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0.4px;
 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the antialiasing optimizations of the browser in conjunction with the non-integer value of your div's width and height. Try to use a size such as 5px or 6px - that should fix it.